# How does VIX interpolate implied volatilities?

Tags: implied-volatility, vix

In the [CBOE VIX white paper](https://pdf4pro.com/cdn/white-paper-cboe-a2ace.pdf) (direct link to PDF), it is explained that once the implied volatility of the near and next-term options $\sigma_1^2$, $\sigma_2^2$ are found, the constant-maturity 30-day implied volatility is calculated as follows:

$$\sqrt{\left\{T_1\sigma_1^2\left[\frac{N_{T_2}-N_{30}}{N_{T_2}-N_{T_1}}\right]+T_2\sigma_2^2\left[\frac{N_{30}-N_{T_1}}{N_{T_2}-N_{T_1}}\right]\right\}\times\frac{N_{365}}{N_{30}}}$$

where
$$\begin{align}
N_{30} &= \text{minutes in $30$ days}\\
N_{365} &= \text{minutes in a $365$-day year}\\
N_{T_1} &= \text{minutes to settlement of near-term options}\\
N_{T_2} &= \text{minutes to settlement of next-term options}\\
T_1 &= \text{time to expiration (in years) for near-term options, i.e.} N_{T_1}/N_{365}\\
T_2 &= \text{time to expiration (in years) for next-term options, i.e.} N_{T_2}/N_{365}\\
\end{align}$$

Now, the formula makes somewhat of an intuitive sense, but I'd like to understand exactly why it's a good method to interpolate implied volatilities and how it was derived. I have searched extensively, both on Google and here, but I didn't find an explanation.

Comment: The formula is basically a linear interpolation in total variance. For a gbm, total variance accrues linearly, so the assumption that's pretty widely used (and is normally "good enough") is that you can linearly interpolate in the total variance space. Provided the curvature is not too high, it's normally a pretty decent approximation.

Comment: @will Thanks for the reply. I tried with an example but I get two different answers. With $\sigma_1^2 = 1.2$, $\sigma_2^2 = 1.7$, $N_{T_1} = 23500$, $N_{T_2} = 65100$ I get $1.556812567$ with VIX's formula and $1.43677885$ with linear interpolation, when I try to interpolate at $N_{30} = 43200$. Is this why you wrote "basically"? Do you know where I can find the exact justification for VIX's formula?

Comment: How does your formula for linear interpolation of the variance differ from the term in squiggly brackets under the square root sign. It seems to me they are the same, so should give the same numerical result.

Comment: @noob2 I'm using the standard linear interpolation formula: $$y = y_1 + (x - x_1) \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$ In this case $x_i = N_{T_i}$ and $y_i = \sigma_i^2$. If you plug in $x = 43200$ you get $y = 1.436...$

Comment: @will Also, linear interpolation is a bit suspicious because if one chooses $N_{T_1}$ and $N_{T_2}$ to be equidistant from $N_{30}$, then the resulting $\sigma_{30}^2$ should also be equidistant from the starting implied volatilities (i.e. their average). However, that's not the case. E.g. take $N_{T_1} = 23500, N_{T_2} = 62900$ and $\sigma_1^2 = 1.2, \sigma_2^2 = 1.7$. With linear interpolation you get $1.45$, with VIX's formula $1.564...$.